# Get data from db, using multiple checkboxes in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have a table called history in which i have a column called PRODUCTS in which the products are saved.
I have a search screen with products using checkboxes, I can get the data if i use only checkbox.
How can i get data if i tick more than one checkboxes.

**Displaying the checkboxes using below code**

```
                                    @foreach($products as $product)
                                        @if (in_array($product->name, explode(" , ",$user->products)) !== false)
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{$product->name}}"
                                                   @if(in_array($product->name, explode(" , ",$user->products))) @endif>
                                            {{$product->name2}}
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
```

**Controller**

public function usersSearch(Request $request, Repair_History $query)

{

$query = $query->newQuery();

```
    if ($request->has('products')) {
        $query->where('proc_doc', $request->input('products'));
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

Comment: Fixed it by using below code



        $friends_checked = $request->input('products');

 if (count($friends_checked) > 1 && is_array($friends_checked))
 {

$query->whereIn('proc_doc', $friends_checked)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using below code in my controller, posting as it might help someone.

```
$friends_checked = $request->input('products'); 
if (count($friends_checked) > 1 && is_array($friends_checked)) { 
    $query->whereIn('proc_doc', $friends_checked) 
}
```